# Why Do I Get Numbers instead of Strings in Basic File I-O?

Tags: c, string, file-io

I am attempting to read input from a file (something I generally have no issue with). However, with the code below, I am currently getting what appears to be garbage data.

The content of the input file (elections.txt):

```
Megan Mann
Sponge Bob
Squid Ward
```

The program:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen ("elections.txt", "r");

    char f_name[20], l_name[20];

    fscanf (fp, "%s", f_name);
    printf ("%s", f_name);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get every time:

```
0
```

Have I somehow de-referenced my pointer, or is the problem more complex? I've done file I-O almost identical to this without any issues.

**SOLVED**
Among some errors in the original code, the program was not able to find the input file on the drive it was saved on, even though they were both in the same folder.

Comment: Why `&` on `fscanf` arguments?

Comment: @Kerrek SB ...I have no idea why I did that.

Comment: @AndreyT I can't remember if character arrays require that operator for scanf functions and it didn't work with or without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fscanf` fails and reads nothing because you never opened your file successfully. `R` is not valid file mode. `r` is what you have to use with `fopen`. It is generally a good idea to check whether `fopen` succeeded by testing `fp` for null.

Also, `%s` format specifier in `fscanf` requires `char *` argument. You are passing `&f_name`, which is `char (*)[20]`. This is incorrect pointer type. Pass `f_name`, not `&fname`.

After fixing the `R` problem, the `%S` problem and removing the `&` from `fscanf` arguments I was able to run your program perfectly fine in my experiment. It read the names from the file and correctly printed them.

Comment: I just caught that typo, thanks for pointing it out. I revised the program based on your input (minus checking for success on fopen, which I am about to do). Now I get '0', which is still confusing.

Comment: @River: Well, I fixed the issues in the original code and your program worked fine for me. If it doesn't work for you, then it probably means that the input file simply does not exist. I.e. the problem is still essentially the same: `fp` is null and `fscanf` reads nothing. The file did not open successfully. One more time: make sure you successfully opened the file before trying to read anything.

Comment: @AndreT I've looked at the folder a thousand times and it has been there, but it was on a virtual drive called OneDrive. Switched it over to my Documents and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

**1.** The second argument to `fopen`, should be lowercase (there's not a lot that you should capitalize in C). Change it to
`fopen("elections.txt", "r");`

**2.** `fscanf` usually takes pointers as arguments, **except** with strings. Because they are arrays of characters, the address is passed to fscanf without `&`. Also, both `%s` specifiers should be lowercase. Change it to:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s", f_name, l_name);
```

Comment: I have done this and revised the question. Unfortunately I am still encountering a number '0' instead of the desired string.

Comment: It works when I test it. Make sure that the file exists, and add a line to check whether `fp` is null.

Comment: Just did so and the program couldn't find the file. They were in the same folder but on a virtual driver called OneDrive. Switched over to my Documents folder and it's working now, with the revisions suggested. Thanks!